# php form not redirecting

Tags: php, forms, redirect, header

This is my code. After submitting the form it just shows blank. It's working fine on localhost server but not on the live server..

```
<?php  
session_start();  
require_once("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");  
require_once("codelibrary/inc/functions.php");  

$name = $_POST['name'];  
$age = $_POST['age'];  
$add = $_POST['add'];  
$no  = $_POST['no'];  
$mob = $_POST['mob'];  
$mail=$_POST['mail'];  


 if($_POST['save'] == "Submit")
    {

      $_SESSION['sess_msg']='Thanks.Your info.has been saved.';
      $result=add_user($name,$age,$add,$no,$mob,$mail);         

      header("location: join.php");
    exit();
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: try removing exit() after header

Comment: show us the `form`, and also, make sure that join.php is on the same folder as the script you posted here. Third, add "echo" after the call to `add_user()` - make sure your call is returned.

Comment: @asprin thats actually suggested practice.

Comment: @Aatch He said it's working on localhost so I made that suggestion.

Comment: the file itself is join .php........i want to redisplay the form with the session message...it do the same but after the blank page displays ..nd if u click on 'back......

Comment: @alfasin you are not supposed to send any output before header() either via echo or via html tags. Please see PHP documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @AshishAgarwal the `echo` is for debug purpose, it's not meant to stay there...

Comment: @alfasin yes, but the fellow says that the code is working on localhost, so it would mean that that portion of the code is correct

Comment: if i remove $_session then how can i set the session message???????

Comment: @AshishAgarwal when you deploy your code to another server - and something isn't working, you should assume that *everything* is possible...

Comment: the code is working fine on my localhost....

Comment: @user1547535 can you please provide more information. For example: What OSes are involved, what are the contents of the `$_POST` variable on the server. All information is useful. Especially when the code works in one place and not another. We know literally nothing about your code or environment. Please remember this.

Comment: @user1547535 so keep working with your localhost. When you're ready to debug, you'll be able to find the source of the problem. good luck!

Comment: @user1547535 try changing the paths of all your files to absolute instead of relative.

Comment: set php.ini to show E_ALL errors and also display_errors=1, maybe it will show you more information. Also post your <form action / method part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove exit() function

if still you face problem try to use

if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['Submit'] !="")

instead of your

if($_POST['save'] == "Submit")

Comment: That's definitely not the problem.

Comment: Lack of `exit()` will do literally nothing.

Comment: guys problem solved.......ishud hav done it with in first step....i just removed exit()..nd it worked........thnx

Answer (score 0):

you are output blanks or other words  before calling header function.

check up error log on live server or execute error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ob_start();` above the line `session_start();`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your script has an error in it, which is terminating the parser. Since your live server should be suppressing errors, try adding

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

to the beginning of the script. Or, if you have access to them, you could check the PHP logs for errors.